# Fastest way to compute matrix multiplication

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multiprocessing

I compute the matrix multiplication as follows:

```
    import numpy as np
    A=np.random.randn(1,3000,30000)
    B=np.random.randn(50,1,30000)
    C=A*B
```

The computation of `C` takes about 10 minutes. How could I improve this?

```
    In [4]: timeit A*B
    1 loops, best of 3: 1min 59s per loop
```

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to improve this? It looks already optimised.

Comment: That's 2 minutes, not 10.

Comment: you could try using pycuda if you've got an nvidia gpu

Comment: @user2357112 it took indeed about 10min, the best loop was 2min.

Comment: @Andy probably because `timeit` runs the code multiple times

Comment: @MohammadAthar Could you provide me a sample code for this? Indeed, I have a MacBook with an additional nvidia

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to complete the computation? The result is (50 * 3000 * 30000 * 64 bits) **36 Gigabytes** in size, on my machine its the swapping that makes it crawl to a halt

Comment: @NilsWerner my RAM is 16GB, but it is swapping, you're right! I include a screenshot. What can I do to stop swapping?

Comment: The safest way to avoid swapping is using (buying) more RAM or using a smaller `dtype`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your main bottleneck is RAM size. The result of your computation is *36 GB in size*, making your operating system write data to swap. You may try to use dask to do out of core computation and directly stream the result to a HDF5 file:

```
import dask
import dask.array

A = dask.array.random.random((1, 3000, 300000), chunks=1024)
B = dask.array.random.random((50, 1, 300000), chunks=1024)

C = A * B

dask.array.to_hdf5('myfile.hdf5', '/C', C)
```

make sure to install

```
pip install dask[array]
pip instal h5py
```

This probably won't speed up your computation as you are still I/O bound (still writing to harddisk), but at least it will make the computation manageable and keep your computer responsive.

Another solution would be to manually slice the operation, if you don't need all of `C` for future computations:

```
for i in B.shape[0]:
    C = A * B[i, ...]  # do not save this result but rather use and discard it immediately
```

Comment: I was running the code and had to stop it, because the hard disk storage was running out of space. The file 'myfile.hdf5' has reached a size of 125GB. What is the reason for this?